# R multiple boxplots in one plot

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a question regarding multiple boxplots. Assume we have data structures like this:

```
a <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
b <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
c <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
```

My task is to create a boxplot of a and b for each group of c. However, it needs to be in the same plot. Ideally: Boxplot for a and b side by side for group 0 and next to it boxplot for a and b for group 1 and all together in one graphic.

I tried several things, but only the seperate plots are working:

```
boxplot(a~as.factor(c))
boxplot(b~as.factor(c))
```

But actually, that's not what I'm searching for. As it has to be one plot.

Comment: ```boxplot()``` is a base R (graphics) function, not ggplot2. But! are you saying you need to have 1 plot containing everything? or do you want 1 code that can put all the plots next to each other? If you want that last one take a look at ```facet_wrap``` and/or ```facet_grid``` from ggplot2

Comment: Thank you, yes I need 1 plot containing everything. I also tried my best with ggplot2, but the same problem occurs here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tidyverse` package for this. You transform your data into long-format that you get three variables: "names", "values" and "group". After that you can plot your boxplots with `ggplot()`:

```r
value_a <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
value_b <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
group <- as.factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5))

data <- data.frame(value_a,value_b,group)

library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(value_a:value_b, names_to = "names", values_to = "values") %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = values, x = group, fill = names))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Noah has already given the `ggplot2` answer that would also be my go to option. As you used the `boxplot` function in the question, this is how to approach it with `boxplot`. You should probably stay consistently within `base` or within `ggplot2` for your publication/presentation.

First we transform the data to a long format (here an option without additional packages):

```
a <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
b <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
c <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)
d <- data.frame(a, b, c)
d <- cbind(stack(d, select = c("a", "b")), c)
```

giving us

```
> head(d)
       values ind c
1 -0.66905293   a 0
2 -0.28778381   a 0
3  0.29148347   a 1
4  0.81380406   a 0
5 -0.85681913   a 0
6 -0.02566758   a 0
```

With which we can then call `boxplot`:

```
boxplot(values ~ ind + c, data = d, at = c(1, 2, 4, 5))
```

[image: Grouped boxplot with base graphics]

The `at` argument controls the grouping and placement of the boxes. Contrary to `ggplot2` you need to choose placing manually, but you also get very fine control of spacing very easily.

Slightly refined version of the plot:

```
boxplot(values ~ ind + c, data = d, at = c(1, 2, 4, 5),
        col = c(2, 4), show.names = FALSE,
        xlab = "")
axis(1, labels= c("c = 0", "c = 1"), at = c(1.5, 4.5))
legend("topright", fill = c(2, 4), legend = c("a", "b"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option using [lattice](https://data-flair.training/blogs/r-lattice-package/) package with `bwplot` function:

```r
library(tidyr)

a <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
b <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
c <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5)

df <- data.frame(a = a,
                 b = b,
                 c = c)

# make longer dataframe
df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = -c)

library(lattice)
bwplot(value ~ name | as.factor(c), df_long)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>